# How to get a function to print something to colon command and let user edit it?

Tags: vimscript, functions, user-input

I need to write a function that when executed it opens `colon` command and paste some stuff on to it and let user edit it before executing the command.

for example

```
function! EditRelativePath()

  :e expand("%")

endfunction
```

so i'm expecting the above code to start a prompt like

```
:e src/user/index.js
```

but it does not simply work, please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
:call feedkeys(':e ' . expand('%'))
```

See [`:help feedkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29) for more details.